# No Image from Google Cloud Storage Bucket in React Native

Tags: image, react-native, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, uri

New to Google Cloud, have a simple reference to an Native Base Image in a google cloud bucket. Using App Engine which works great with Database in Cloud Storage.  I don't see any debugger messages or errors.  The image just doesn't show, empty box.  The image link works when put into a browser.

Tools->React Native, Node, Express on Google App Engine.

Inside a Flatlist:

```
Thumbnail style={{width: 40, height: 40, borderRadius: 40/2}} 
                source={uri: 'imagesource'}} />
```

Comment: When you reference to the image from the app engine instance, are using a service account? or how are you accesing to the image? Also take a look at this [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-storage)

Comment: Yes, I saw that for Node/Express saving a file to bucket.  But do I need to go thru that to reference an image?   If I received the public url, shouldn't I be able to reference it directly from inside my react-native app?   Do I need to call the image from Express?

Comment: I get it know, does your image in the bucket has public access enable? Make sure your domain has access or that the image has anonymous access. [Check this out](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public)